# Decimal to IP address in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a data table in SQL which is using decimal to record IP addresses for the computers.

Any SQL command will be work for query them into address?

Comment: Why not use a varchar for that?

Comment: please show some sample data and expected ouput

Comment: @MisterPositive I'm trying to use SQL Report builder to query the record. seem the output was not able to convert to  IP Address

Comment: @TheGameiswar The data in the table is 3232235777 and the expected output should be 192.168.1.1

Comment: I don't see that working out for you.

Answer (score 0):

> The data in the table is 3232235777 and the expected output should be 192.168.1.1

Based off of the example you've given, you won't be able to convert that string of numbers( or decimal ) into any meaningful IP address entry. The column would need to be some type of VarChar or Nvarchar.  But the difficulty would be creating the correct mask to parse out the IP address.